# Can not get background notifications in android using flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to push notifications with flutter , foreground notifications works well but when in background it does not get any notification .

here is my code

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
```

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String token = '';
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getToken();

    firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true, badge: true, provisional: true, sound: true);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessage: $message");
    });


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
    });


    super.initState();
  }

  void getToken() async {
    token = (await firebaseMessaging.getToken())!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Token : $token")),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(token);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.print),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Code isn't visible in your post. Are notification permissions allowed?

Comment: now it is shown @HuthaifaMuayyad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a top-level named handler,
since the last firebase_messaging 10.0.6. Notifications will work in the background
first update your firebase_messaging 10.0.6

/// Define a top-level named handler which background/terminated messages will
/// call.
///
/// To verify things are working, check out the native platform logs.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

see here the complete example: [firebase_messaging/example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example)

if you need a real project example [complete example](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example)

Comment: Unfortunately I added it and it doesn't work

Comment: You're doing something wrongly i implement it, and it works for me, pay attention it only works on android stock version it won't work on Xiaomi devices for example here is a complete example https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example